# Error when I try to delete rows from TableView and SQL in swift

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite, uitableview, sql-delete

I have a following question:
I have a function in which I'm deleting an object from an array and from Table View and I also call a function that deletes this object from SQL.

```
func deleteNote(noteId: Int32) {
        connect()

        var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(
            database,
            "DELETE FROM notes WHERE rowid = \(noteId)",
            -1,
            &statement,
            nil
        ) == SQLITE_OK {
            if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Error deleting note")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error creating note update statement")
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }
```

This is a function that deletes from SQL.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            notes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
            NoteManager.shared.deleteNote(noteId: notes[indexPath.row].id)
        }
    }
```

And this is the main function.

When I delete rows nothing wrong happens however, when I reach the last one I get this error:

[image]

Maybe it is also worth noting that when I asked my program to print me the id of each deleted row it starts from 4 and increments by one with each deleted row.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try calling `NoteManager.shared.deleteNote` before `notes.remove`. You try to access the id of a note after you have deleted it.

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved the problem.